# $\int_{-\pi/2} ^ {\pi/2} cos^2(t) dt = \int_{-1}^{1} \sqrt {1-x^2} dx = \frac{\pi}{2}$

Tags: integration

Can somebody explain this integral to me? I know about Weierstrass substitution, but that doesn't fully explains it.

I'm majorily confused on how $\sqrt{1-x²}$ becomes $cos(t)^2$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Substitute $$x=\sin(t)$$ and $$dx=\cos(t)dt$$